# How to host multiple projects on a single domain? (For free)

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, deployment, dns, hosting

**Good morning!**

As mentioned in the title, I'd like to host multiple projects on a domain which from now on we'll call xyz.com .
I have an (ugly) personal developer portfolio, made with React after my web dev campus. Now that I'm a bit more experienced, I made a personal software that I'd like to use for a business of mine (with Vue.js, as I use it at my office job and I'm way more comfortable with it).

**The thing is:** I'd like to host my platform on xyz.com ; and the portfolio on a route like xyz.com/developer-portfolio.
This should be pretty easy, if those just weren't **2 separate projects**.

I tried platforms like **Netlify and Vercel** but they both give you **just 1 concurrent build**, and I can assign a domain just on one project at a time, therefore the platform OR the portfolio.

What would you suggest I do? I'm eager to use/explore different technologies, as long as we keep everything free.

Many thanks for reading and support!

I tried:

- moving both projects in a single repo and try to host them together in a single project in Netlify and Vercel, didn't work as both the platforms give you just 1 concurrent build
- creating 2 different projects on those platform, didn't work as I can assign xyz.com just to 1 project at a time
- put both projects in a single repo, where I have ./frontend and ./portfolio , then put on netlify.toml:
  [build]
  command = "cd FrontEnd && npm install && npm run build && cd ../portfolio && npm install && npm run build && cd ../"
  publish = "dist/"
  This works as Netlify successfully builds both the projects but when I go to the link Netlify provides me I get a **404**.

Answer (score 0):

You could use subdomains such as `portfolio.xyz.com` and `platform.xyz.com` which you would deploy on the 2 separate platforms (or projects on the same platform, if that's possible for free). You would only need to change the DNS configuration to redirect to each individual platform.